# Why doesn't pydoc work when I use argparse?

Tags: python, pydoc

Still very new to python, so forgive me if this seems obvious, but
I found that argparse prevents me running pydoc on my script.

```
"""
  Script to blah blah blah
"""

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script to do something useful')

# If I uncomment this line, pydoc fails !
#args = parser.parse_args()
```

If I uncomment that last line, and run **pydoc** *scriptname*, then pydoc appears to try running the script somehow, rather than just showing a formatted docstring ??

Where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

`pydoc` *imports* the file which means that argparse will then do it's thing.  The typical way around this is to set up a conditional that will only run iff the module is imported as the main module:

```
"""
  Script to blah blah blah
"""

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script to do something useful')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
```

This is a really well used and understood idiom in the python community, so there isn't any magic going on here that will give your future readers a hard time.  Basically, every module has a `__name__` attribute (which is the name of the module).  The "master" module (the one where python starts it's execution) gets the special name `__main__` instead of the typical file basename without the extension.

Comment: Thanks for the rapid response and clarification.  I get it now !